# Adding an autoincrement column to query results

Tags: sql, sqlite

Without creating a TEMP table with an autoincrement column, how can add an auto-incrementing field to a query result? For example,

```
SELECT ???, * FROM MyTable
```

Should result in:

```
1|*
2|*
3|*
```

Comment: What do you need the autoincrement column for?

Comment: As an index going into a grid that uses the index key for fetching subsets of the query result. Currently I ended up with a TEMP table with an autoincrement value - but it feels hackish.

Comment: Fetching from where? From the database, or from the data stored in the grid?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for row numbers. Try something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(0) 
        FROM supportContacts t1 
        WHERE t1.id <= t2.id 
        ) AS 'Row Number', * FROM supportContacts t2 ORDER BY id;
```

Example table:

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id ║  type   ║       details       ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Email   ║ admin@sqlfiddle.com ║
║  2 ║ Twitter ║ @sqlfiddle          ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Result:

```
╔════════════╦════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ Row Number ║ id ║  type   ║       details       ║
╠════════════╬════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║          1 ║  1 ║ Email   ║ admin@sqlfiddle.com ║
║          2 ║  2 ║ Twitter ║ @sqlfiddle          ║
╚════════════╩════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/04eca/271)

Comment: This does not work if the query result is not ordered by the `id` column (often, there is no such column), or if some records are filtered out, or if some records of the table with the `id` column are duplicated in the query result. ([example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c8e10/2))

Comment: @CL. - Actually you have to give condition (i.e. `where type like '%t%'`) also in a sub query. (see [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c8e10/2))

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that Himanshu's answer worked 100% for me. I am not the OP but I found this thread when I needed a solution. Here is the code I used with more generic table names.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(0)  
    FROM ENTRIES t1  
    WHERE t1.Created_Date<= t2.Created_Date  
    ) AS 'id', * FROM ENTRIES t2  
    WHERE Team = 'Sales' 
    ORDER BY id
```